# Laravel scheduler breaking function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that runs fine except when being called in the scheduler even though its the exact same code, when I run it with the scheduler i get a soap error that Im not getting normally. I've spent hours and cant figure out what about the scheduler is causing it, laravel version is 5.1.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Classes\ImportexportDomains;
use App\Accounts;
use App\Settings;
use App\Client;
use App\Trunk;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Phone;
use App\Makemodel;

require_once(app_path() . "/kashflow/_include/kashflow.inc.php");
require_once(app_path() . "/kashflow/_include/kashflowinvoice.inc.php");

class BillVoip extends Command {

    protected $name = 'bill:voip';

    public function fire() {
        try {
            $parameters['UserName'] = 'accounts@xxx.co.uk';
            $parameters['Password'] = 'xxxx';
            $kashflow_customer_id = 22766679;
            $invoice_number = 1;
            $invoice_date = date('Y-m-d');
            $due_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice_date . '+7 days'));
            $ref = '';

// Connect to Kashflow.
            $kashflow = new \Kashflow($parameters['UserName'], $parameters['Password']);


// Initialise the invoice.
            $invoicekf = new \KashflowInvoice($kashflow_customer_id, $invoice_number, $invoice_date, $due_date, $ref);

            $rate = 10;
            $quantity = 1;
            $nominal_id = 12868556; //nom id for domain renewal
            $description = 'Domain Renewal - ';
            $invoicekf->addLine($quantity, $rate, 0, 20, $nominal_id, $description);

            $response = $kashflow->insertInvoice($invoicekf);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
// Damn.

            $error = 'There was an error sending invoice to Kashflow: ' . $e->getMessage();

            echo $error;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the code - it works if I link to a page with it on but when trying to run from the scheduler I get this error

```
  [ErrorException]
  SoapVar::SoapVar(): Invalid type ID
```

Comment: You need to show your error and some code that you have tried.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst I have added the code and error

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Anyone fixed this?